# target variable refernce name of a event listener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, flash-cs5

How to get the target variable refernce name of a event listener

```
   var key1:BtnKey=new BtnKey;
    var key2:BtnKey=new BtnKey;
    key1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent):void{
                checkAnswer(e,qset)
            });
    key2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent):void{
                checkAnswer(e,qset)
            });

function checkAnswer(e:MouseEvent,qset:Number):void{
//here I want the target variable reference ("key1" or "key2")  
    //e.target only gives the movieclip refernce like "[Object BtnKey]"
}
```

`

Comment: You can't get the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.currentTarget` to get the button that was clicked on. If you need to find out whether you have `key1` or `key2`, use a strict equality comparison:

```
if (e.currentTarget === key1) {
    // Do something
} else if (e.currentTarget === key2) {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: e.currentTarget gives '[Object BtnKey]' , not key1 or key2

Comment: `[Object BtnKey]` is correct - this is the type of key1 and key2. Just try `trace(key1)` or `trace(key2)` and you'll get the same result. If you use the strict equality comparison I mentioned you can find out whether it's key1 or key2 in the event handler.

Comment: when I trace(e.currentTarget), gives '[Object BtnKey]',but (e.currentTarget === key1) works..!! thank you.